# Design APIs using HTTP methods

Tags: rest, soap, graphql, grpc, api-design

I was asked below question in Netskope system design interview. i.e. design APIs for below functionalities (full URL path with HTTP method) and I could not answer well so I was rejected. I could not find a solution using Google search. Can you please provide some solution?

1. Create Virtual Machine
2. Reboot Virtual Machine
3. Shutdown Virtual Machine

My solution

```
POST www.netskope.com/v1/create_vm/args?machineid="ABC"
POST www.netskope.com/v1/reboot_vm/args?machineid="ABC"
POST www.netskope.com/v1/shutdown_vm/args?machineid="ABC"
```

Comment: Was the question as generic as "APIs using HTTP methods"? It's tagged gRPC, GraphQL and SOAP but these technologies aren't reflected in your solution.

Comment: I mean interviewer said I can design using any style REST or gRPC or SOAP or GraphQL. I just tried using REST because I don't know other styles much but if you can give a solution in other styles I will accept it.

Comment: Got it. You have one, good answer already and can only have one answer. Instead, I recommend you look at published APIs by the Cloud provides for examples. Google publishes its APIs as both HTTP/REST and gRPC. For Compute Engine, the HTTP/REST VM create method is called [`instances.insert`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert).

Comment: The equivalent gRPC method is defined in [compute.proto](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/googleapis/master/google/cloud/compute/v1/compute.proto) you'll have to grep the file but look for `rpc Insert(InsertInstanceRequest) returns (Operation)`.

Answer (score 2):

here are some thoughts on your solution and why it could've been rejected:

1. **Endpoint Format**: In your initial solution, you're using a URL
   structure that includes the action (create_vm, reboot_vm,
   shutdown_vm) as part of the endpoint path. While this is a
   straightforward approach, it's not as organized or intuitive for
   developers and clients consuming your API.
2. **HTTP Method**: You're using the HTTP POST method for all three
   actions. While POST can be used for creating resources, it's
   typically used for operations that modify or add new resources.
   Rebooting and shutting down virtual machines are actions that can be
   considered modifications of existing resources, but they might not
   fit perfectly under the "create" action.
3. **Query Parameters**: You're passing the machine ID as a query
   parameter. While this is a valid approach, it's more common to
   include data in the request body for actions that require more
   information. Query parameters are often used for filtering or
   identifying resources, not necessarily for passing detailed
   information needed for an action.
4. **Lack of Consistency**: Your initial solution lacks consistency in
   terms of URL structure and HTTP method usage. Each action has a
   different URL and the same HTTP method (POST) is used for all
   actions, which might confuse developers and make the API less
   user-friendly.
5. **RESTful Design**: RESTful design principles aim for consistency,
   predictability, and intuitive URL structures. This includes using
   appropriate HTTP methods (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE) and representing
   resources and actions clearly in the URL paths.

---

Here is an explanation how a correct solution would look like, and why:

**1. Create Virtual Machine:**

To create a virtual machine, you can use the HTTP POST method along with the resource URL (note that the `www.netskope.com` part is truncated here and onwards as it's a common case in describing REST endpoints):

- **Endpoint:** `POST /v1/virtual-machines`
- **Request Body:** JSON payload containing the necessary information to create a VM
- **Response:** Status code indicating success or failure, and possibly the newly created VM details

**Example Request:**

```http
POST /v1/virtual-machines
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "machineId": "ABC",
    "specs": {
        "cpu": 2,
        "memory": "4GB",
        "storage": "100GB"
    }
}
```

**Example Response:**

```json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Virtual machine created successfully",
    "vmDetails": {
        "machineId": "ABC",
        "status": "running",
        "specs": {
            "cpu": 2,
            "memory": "4GB",
            "storage": "100GB"
        }
    }
}
```

---

**2. Reboot Virtual Machine:**

To reboot a virtual machine, you can use the HTTP POST or PUT method:

- **Endpoint:** `POST /v1/virtual-machines/{machineId}/reboot`
- **Request Body:** Empty or minimal, as reboot usually doesn't require additional information
- **Response:** Status code indicating success or failure, and possibly a message

**Example Request:**

```http
POST /v1/virtual-machines/ABC/reboot
```

**Example Response:**

```json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Virtual machine rebooted successfully"
}
```

---

**3. Shutdown Virtual Machine:**

To shut down a virtual machine, you can again use the HTTP POST or PUT method:

- **Endpoint:** `POST /v1/virtual-machines/{machineId}/shutdown`
- **Request Body:** Empty or minimal
- **Response:** Status code indicating success or failure, and possibly a message

**Example Request:**

```http
POST /v1/virtual-machines/ABC/shutdown
```

**Example Response:**

```json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Virtual machine shutdown successful"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your valuable time to answer my question. I have better clarity now. In your Reboot virtual machine example you specified "reboot" in Endpoint path, can we make reboot in the Request body? Similar with Shutdown virtual machine example.

Comment: Technically, we can, but we must generalize the endpoint and pass some parameters (e.g. "action") in the request body in this case. For example,

POST /v1/virtual-machines/{machineId}

and the body:

{
    "action": "reboot",
    "some_parameter": "some_value"
}

But generally, it's not the best approach in this case, as the reboot and shutdown are simple operations and don't require many parameters

You can also check out the guidelines for Web API design: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design#organize-the-api-design-around-resources